# Not able to see logs when I login as community user

Tags: community

I have a contact record and I login to community user from that using "Manage External User". I have case creation process in community portal in the form of visualforce. When I explore the same, no logs are displayed in the "Debug Logs". Can any one of you please help me out.

Comment: Found out the cause. I was adding a wrong user. My mistake !!!!

Comment: If you don't need an answer to this question, you might consider deleting it since it won't provide value to other users of the community.